# Unable to add Style to last item of Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I am using [Bootstrap's Progress Bar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) inside a repeater to show score of different items. The aspx is like this:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptFinalScore" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptFinalScore_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-2">
            <asp:Label ID="rpt_Score" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TotalScore") %>'>></asp:Label>
        </div>                    
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="progress">
                <div id="rpt_proBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" runat="server">                                                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and the codebehind is:

```
protected void rptFinalScore_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptFinalScore.Items)
    {                
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var Score = item.FindControl("rpt_Score") as Label;
            var ProgBar = item.FindControl("rpt_proBar") as HtmlGenericControl;
            string BuildingScore = ((Label)Score).Text;
            ProgBar.Attributes.Add("style", string.Format("width:{0}%;", BuildingScore));           
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that if suppose there are 5 items in the repeater then it will correctly apply the `style="width:x%"` to first 4 items but not for the last item. The output is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dToGR.jpg). Can someone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you looping in each ItemDataBound event handler call ? You have to set styles for the corresponding item that's stored in e argument. Last item's style is not set because repeater doesn't have that item in its Items collection when ItemDataBound event is fired.
You have to change your ItemDataBound handler to something like this:

```
protected void rptFinalScore_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{             
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var Score = e.Item.FindControl("rpt_Score") as Label;
            var ProgBar = e.Item.FindControl("rpt_proBar") as HtmlGenericControl;
            string BuildingScore = ((Label)Score).Text;
            ProgBar.Attributes.Add("style", string.Format("width:{0}%;", BuildingScore));           
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you also please tell me why the repeater doesn't have that item in its Items collection when ItemDataBound event is fired for the last item ?

Comment: That's how repeater's event pipeline works, an item's ItemDataBound fires before it's added to repeaters items collection.